# Error when making an instance of Eq typeclass in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am learning Haskell and writing a small decision diagrams library as a starting project. I have declared the data type as

```
data DD a = DDNode { var :: Int, vals :: [DD a]} | DDLeaf { val :: a} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

For testing for equality between 2 DDs, I am making an instance of Eq for DD. It basically does the same as testing for node and leaf equality in the case of tree structures.

```
instance (Eq a) => DD a where
    (DDNode i vs) == (DDNode i' vs') = i == i' && vs == vs'
    (DDLeaf v) == (DDLeaf v') = v == v'
    _ ==  _ = False
```

When I load a file with the above code in GHCi, I get the following error,

```
Prelude> :load decisionDiagrams.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling DecisionDiagram  ( decisionDiagrams.hs, interpreted )

decisionDiagrams.hs:9:19: error:
    ‘==’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘DD’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use `Eq` both in `deriving` and in an `instance` declaration, since then there are *two* implementations. The `deriving (Eq)` should thus be removed:

```
data DD a
  = DDNode { var :: Int, vals :: [DD a]}
  | DDLeaf { val :: a}
  deriving (Show)
```

You need to specify that you are defining an instance of `Eq`, so the `instance` declaration should look like:

```
--                 ↓ defining an instance for Eq
instance (Eq a) => Eq (DD a) where
    -- …
```

The `Eq` instance you are implementing, is the one that Haskell can automatically derive. You thus do not need to construct such instance yourself: you can do this with a `deriving` clause. There is thus no reason to implement `Eq` manually.